# Teamcity integration with old project requires teamcity.dotnet.vstest.14.0

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, teamcity

I need to integrate old projects with new agents on our teamcity server. I need to provide path to `teamcity.dotnet.vstest.14.0`. I have found that installation of VisualStudio test tools can be achieved by installing Agents for Visual Studio 2015. However, I cannot find the package anymore on the Microsoft site. There are Agents for 2013/2017/2019, but not for 2015 anymore (I've checked the old download distributions). I've tried to copy and paste package from old agent to a new one, but that didn't work as it need to be installed. Is there any workaround for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TeamCity auto-detects MSTest based on the registry values that describe the Visual Studio installation path. If Visual Studio is installed in a non-standard location, or the registry key is corrupted, or the TeamCity agent has no access to the VisualStudio directory, TeamCity may not be able to detect MSTest. In this case, the corresponding configuration parameter of the `%teamcity.dotnet.mstest.xx.yy%` format must be added to the build manually. It should contain the full path including the `MSTest.exe` executable, e.g. the default path for `MSTest 2013` is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe`

p.s. 
you need to specify a different directory for the config parameter:

`teamcity.dotnet.vstest.14.0 : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe`